# C++11 std::array slice

Tags: c++, c++11, stdarray

I have a matrix like this:

```
array<array<double, DISMAX>, DISMAX> Md;
```

and a vector like this:

```
array<double, DISMAX> matrixLine;
```

`DISMAX` is a constant.
My question: How can I copy that vector to one line of the matrix without using a for loop? Is it possible?

Comment: 1) By writing the code to do it; 2) Yes, it's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest method is to do the obvious:

```
Md[0] = matrixLine;
```

There is still a loop but the `std::array` hides the details.

Answer (score 0):

Copy assignment, *e.g.*, `Md[0] = matrixLine`, should work just fine.